# Teradata createClob: function not supported in this version. Is this a bug or a feature?

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata, clob

I am trying to test `createClob()` method

```
String conStr  = "jdbc:teradata://...";  
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"); 
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr, "user", "pass"); 

Clob clobTest = conn.createClob();
```

However it throws the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 165] [SQLState HY000] createClob: function not supported in this version
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:94)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:69)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.createClob(TDSession.java:1479)
```

I downloaded the latest [version](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver)    of jdbc
Why the error?  What does it mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc of [`createClob()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createClob--) says:

> `SQLException` - if an object that implements the `Blob` interface can not be constructed, this method is called on a closed connection or a database access error occurs.
>   `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` - if the JDBC driver does not support this data type

So technically this should have thrown a `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` if Teradata does not support blobs, but that is just a minor 'bug'.

The only thing you can do is file an improvement request to ask them to implement this.